# Middle click on trackball

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, mouse, monterey, bettertouchtool

I just upgraded to a M1 Monterey Mac and I have a Kensington orbit trackball with two mouse buttons. On Pre-Monterey, I could (with Kensington Trackball works) press the left and right mouse button simultaneously and get a middle click.

Is there a software that can do this on Monterey?

BetterTouchTool didn't seem to have support for this, and steermouse required holding one mouse button and then pressing the other, rather than simultaneously pressing both.

Comment: Have you tried [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)?

Comment: @agarza -- that worked great! if you put that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark that as accepted. Saved me from buying another trackball since it was driving me insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). It allows you to configure the keys or buttons on a USB device that is seen as a keyboard or mouse.

Karabiner Elements gives you two ways to set up a device both simple and complex. And another major plus for the software is that it's free.

Here are the core features:

> - **Simple Modifications**: Change normal keys to other keys.
> - **Complex Modifications**: Change keys by complex rules.
>
>   - Change a key to combination of modifiers. (e.g. change capslock to control+command)
>   - Change modifiers+key to key. (e.g. change control+m to return)
>   - Send key events if a key is pressed alone.
>   - Send key events if keys are pressed simultaneously.
>   - Mouse keys.
>   - etc.
> - **Function Keys**: Change f1-f12 keys to media controls.
> - **Devices**: Apply modifications to specified keyboards only.
> - **Profiles**: Support multiple profiles.
> - **Modifier Flag Sync**: Synchronize modifier flags across all connected keyboards.
> - **Secure Keyboard Entry Support**: Work well on Secure Keyboard Entry environment such as a password prompt, terminal with Secure
>   Keyboard Entry, etc.

(I was able to get a Belkin n52 gamepad from 2003 that ran on Mac OS 10.1.2 to run on Monterey.)